# How to find the first date of a month from a given datetime dataset (in SQL Oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, datetime

Does any in-built function exists for that please?

I've created this one;

`to_char( add_months( ( last_day( sysdate ) + 1 ), -1 ), 'dd/mm/yyyy' )`

Thanks in advance. Chri$

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`TRUNC()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) with a date format argument:

`select trunc(sysdate, 'MON') from dual`